# character is of string is always changing the position when ever I change the string value by using CCLabelBMFont

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I update the score label when I'm playing my game and I display it by using `CCLabelBMFont`, when the score changes, each character of the score label always change the position of the label.

I want to keep it the same position!

Example: 00:01 take small space than 00:50; when the text change the `CCLabelBMFont` reposition the text again. help me , how to keep the same position?

Comment: Set centre-alignment?

Comment: if your font is variable pitch, you will never achieve the 'fixed' appearance you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your bitmap font was created from a true type font that has a variable width.

Only fixed-width fonts like Courier will give you the same string width for the same amount of characters in the string. Strings drawn with non-fixed-width fonts will have varying width depending on the characters in the font, ie a 'w' character has greater width than an 'i' character.

Open FontBook.app (it comes with every Mac) and in the Collection panel select "Fixed Width" to see only the fonts with a fixed width. On my system I have these fixed width fonts installed:

[image]

FYI, Monaco is the default font used by Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell by the question, but my guess is that you are talking about the actual positioning of your label changing, meaning your alignment is not what you want it to be (justified left instead of justified right for instance).

```
Left Justified:
test
testtest

Right Justified:
    test
testtest
```

If this is what you are talking about, you can change the text alignment by changing the nodes anchor point.

```
// for right justified
label.anchorPoint = ccp(1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are saying "always changing the position", do you mean "left side isn't staying in the same place"?

`CCNode` class has `anchorPoint` property, which determines which point of this node is "pinned" to the point in node's parent. Anchor point of (0, 0) means bottom left corner, (1, 1) - top right, (0.5, 0.5) - center. All positioning and transformations take place around anchor point.

Set `anchorPoint` property of your label to mean the point which you want to have "pinned" when content size of label changes. Examples:

if you want top left corner to be stationary:

```
label.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 1);
```

if you want the middle of left side to be stationary:

```
label.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0.5);
```